# Transfer storage from stock recovery to PC

Tags: samsung, recovery-mode, data-recovery

I made my backups and everything before attempting to upgrade to the latest security patch on my rooted phone (SM-G781B), but because of laziness ("it's gonna work 100%"), I didn't transfer them to my PC or my external drive.

After flashing BL, CP, HOME_CSC and Magisk-patched AP it now got into a boot loop (I don't know why, maybe it's because I downloaded the firmware via another way since [Bifrost](https://github.com/zacharee/SamloaderKotlin/) didn't seem to work anymore) and I only can access stock recovery and download mode.

I am going to need to do a factory reset or clean flash, but before that I'd like to obtain my backups stored on the internal SD card. ADB displays "unauthorized" but I can choose to sideload something. Is there any way to do that or is it impossible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your phone is rooted I assume your bootloader is unlocked. If this is the case you are free to boot or flash a different recovery ROM which offers more functionality than the stock recovery ROM.

I know that some recovery ROMs like TWRP have support for accessing encrypted user data. This way you should be able to access and copy/extract the backup files that are still stored on your user data partition.